# Displaying time in Python using "Strptime()"

Tags: python, time

I'm trying to make a basic program that shows how many days are left until your next birthday, however when I run it in terminal, it says that the input value should be returning a string not an integer? when using the input function in python, doesnt it automatically return as a string value?

```
    import datetime
    currentDate = datetime.date.today()

    userinput = input("Please enter your birthday(MM.DD.YY)")
    birthday = datetime.datetime.strptime(userinput, "%m/%d/%Y")
    print(birthday)
```

Comment: It does in Python 3.x...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use `%y` (small letter) to catch two digit years
2. You should advice the user about the expected format - you expect "MM/DD/YY", but you tell the user to type "MM.DD.YY"

To calculate the difference use something like this (for python3, for python2 use raw_input as Jahangir mentioned):

```
import datetime
today = datetime.date.today()

userinput = input("Please enter your birthday(MM/DD):")
birthday = datetime.datetime.strptime(userinput, "%m/%d")
birthday = datetime.date(year=today.year, month=birthday.month, day=birthday.day)

if (birthday-today).days<0:
    birthday = datetime.date(year=today.year+1, month=birthday.month, day=birthday.day)

print("%d days to your next birthday!"%(birthday-today).days)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @Guntherjena !

Answer (score 2):

In Python 2 use [raw_input()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) instead.